# Get Code signing certificate from assembly when the assembly is embedded in host application

Tags: c#

I'm having an issue with my workflow, I need to be able to get the code sign certificate from
[Single file deployment and executables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/single-file)  or even worse [compress the assembly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/single-file#compress-assemblies-in-single-file-app)

The following application settings will break the code signing certificate extraction

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    <PublishSingleFile>true</PublishSingleFile>
    <SelfContained>true</SelfContained>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
    <PublishReadyToRun>true</PublishReadyToRun>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

This will not work if a client uses the above single file app settings:

```
var self = typeof(MyClass).Assembly;
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(self.Location))
{
   return null;
}
return X509Certificate2.CreateFromSignedFile(self.Location);
```

I have no control over the end dll and I also do not want to as developers should be free to use the deployment settings that best fits their needs, I, however, would like to get the codesign certificate...